# Android custom ListView (list with TextView and EditText) along with other views at top and bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-custom-view

I have a custom ListView consisting of TextView and EditText.
At the top of the listView
RelativeLayout - 2 TextView 
LinearLayout(horizontal) - EditText & ImageView 
At the bottom of the ListView
LinearLayout(horizontal) - 2 Button
.The parent Layout is LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="66dp"
            android:background="#6BFC83" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fieldText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
                android:text="Credited Amt"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fieldText"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fieldText"
                android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fieldText"
                android:hint="Amount"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/listText"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="left"
           android:layout_weight="2"
           android:ems="10"
           android:hint="Search item" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>  

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"                
            android:src="@drawable/plus50" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:focusable="false" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:text="History" />
        </LinearLayout>           

    </LinearLayout>
```

The Layout looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wa8qw8ey9l6n77v/snap1.PNG)

When I focus on the EditText in the custom listview, it is completely hidden like
[this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qyi8tpmujp46vt6/snap2.PNG)

I have looked for addHeaderView() and addFooterView, but in those tutorials, they have used them in different xml files.
Please help me! Am just a noob. Sorry if its a duplicate question.

Comment: you don't want to create different xmls??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest file

define this inside activity tag.

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"`

Comment: Thanks a lot...! Can you please explain how its working?

Also, shall I ask one more question? Using the ImageView "plus", user can add new list item. But when he adds, the values already present in the exising list item fades away? How shall I persist the values?

Comment: Use onClick method inside your adapter for it. and then inflate layout

Comment: what am asking is, is there any built in facility for that? or should I hard code it?

Comment: see there is no such kind of built in facility, you have to make it on your way in your custom adapter.